# White Horizontal Line Longtables

Tags: tables, color

I want to create a table like this.

[image: Example Table]

So I used xcolor to give alternating colors as this.

This is what I got.

[image]

Q1 ) Do you know how to generate white vertical rule get the effect shown red ? (I need white borders. I have to keep the tables' size fixed always and have to use may tables like this which goes across the pages.)

Q2) Is it possible to center align 2nd column while keeping same width?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined\else\usepackage{times}\fi
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,head=0.5in,foot=0.4in] {geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\definecolor{BackColor}{RGB}{255,245,245}
\definecolor{AnnexColor}{RGB}{220,230,255}
\definecolor{GrayColor}{RGB}{220,220,220}

\let\oldlongtable\longtable
\let\endoldlongtable\endlongtable
\renewenvironment{longtable}{\rowcolors{3}{BackColor}{AnnexColor}\oldlongtable} {
\endoldlongtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{p{4.15in}p{0.85in}}\\
\rowcolor{GrayColor} \textit{\textbf{Link}} & \textit{\textbf{Count}} \\
/AJAX/infotitle.php & 1 \\
/search.php & 1 \\
/artists.php & 1 \\
/product.php & 1 \\
/userinfo.php & 2 \\
/AJAX/infoartist.php & 1 \\
/AJAX/infocateg.php & 1 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use a preamble of p{4.15in}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.85in} and put \arrayrulecolor{white} before the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's only *that* vertical line that has to be white, here is a solution. I slightly improved the vertical spacing in your table with the `cellspace` package, and replaced you patching longtable with a call to `etoolbox` and its `AtBeginEnvironment` command, to have  ashorter code. The second column is now centred.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined\else\usepackage{times}\fi
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,head=0.5in,foot=0.4in] {geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\definecolor{BackColor}{RGB}{255,245,245}
\definecolor{AnnexColor}{RGB}{220,230,255}
\definecolor{GrayColor}{RGB}{220,220,220}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\rowcolors{3}{BackColor}{AnnexColor}}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{S{p{4.15in}}! {\color{white}\vrule width1pt}Sc}%
\rowcolor{GrayColor} \textit{\bfseries Link} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{0.85in}}{\textit{\bfseries Count}} \\
/AJAX/infotitle.php & 1 \\
/search.php & 1 \\
/artists.php & 1 \\
/product.php & 1 \\
/userinfo.php & 2 \\
/AJAX/infoartist.php & 1 \\
/AJAX/infocateg.php & 1 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]